# Trying to edit the page title template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I am trying to edit the template used to generate page titles on product pages.

I have duplicated:
`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml`

into my theme folder:
`app/design/frontend/MyDirectory/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml`

I thought that Magento picked up this new version of the file, but it does not seem to be recognizing the new template.

Am I missing some obvious step here?

Answer (score 3):

Your folder structure isn't correct `app/design/frontend/MyDirectory/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml`. It should be: `app/design/frontend/MyDirectory/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml`

You can read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your folder structure.

First you have to follow magento guidelines to create theme.

Themename are keeps in smallletter. Ex. **`mytheme`** instead of **`MyTheme`**

In override theme you doesn't need to create view folder inside `Vendor_Module` folder.

Your file path keep like below,

> app/design/frontend/**MyDirectory/mytheme**/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml

After create file inside `html` folder just run command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now your changes are display in site.